# "You must be a developer of the application" while accessing unified_thread

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I get this response each time I want to access my chat history with a user:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) You must be a developer of the application", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 298
  }
}
```

**The FQL query I use:**

```
SELECT message_id, sender, body 
FROM unified_message 
WHERE thread_id IN 
(SELECT thread_id FROM unified_thread WHERE single_recipient = 'XXXX')
ORDER BY timestamp desc;
```

**The tool I use:**
Facebook Graph Explorer

**The token I use:**

app: my app

user: a non-developer account

**My app settings:**
marked as "Live and available to all users"

From what I've read, unified_thread was once restricted to developer accounts as it was being deployed by facebook, but today any doc says that we can use this table.

If I switch to a token with a developer account, it works of course.

Are there some restrictions to use these tables I'm not aware of?